# Highlight rows in listbox from values in recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

On my forms Load event I'm loading a list of clients from sql table.  On my Current even I'm trying to loop the listbox and highlight rows from my recordset.
I have this but it's not working.  what am I missing?

```
For i = 0 To Me.ClientList.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ClientList.Column(0, i) = rs.Fields(0) Then
     Me.ClientList.Selected(i) = True
     rs.MoveNext
    End If

Next
```

Comment: What do you mean by highlight? And have you tried stepping through the code using F8? That should clarify what does (not) happen.

Comment: I mean show as selected.

Comment: Ah, you want to pre-select an entry when the form opens, got it. Is the inner code of the `If` ever reached? If not, then the comparison is wrong; as suggested before, you should step through the code and look at what the two terms of the comparison actually contain.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was that the `Me.ClientList.ItemData` was text value and `rs.Fields(0)` was int.  So use `CInt` to convert and it will evaluate correctly. Hope this helps.

```
If CInt(Me.ClientList.ItemData(i)) = rs.Fields(0) Then
         Me.ClientList.Selected(i) = True
         rs.MoveNext
End If
```